# In Rich:ExtendedTable tag, how can I set the drag-and-drop property for the columns as false?

Tags: css, richfaces

[image]

I have a very specific requirement: the headers in the rich-extended data-table **should not be draggable**. I searched for the RichFaces classes and found about the `rf-edt-rsz` class, which can be used to disable the column resizing property, which I did.

But the last thing of the task, *disabling drag-n-drop property for the columns* is what I'm looking for. If anyone can provide me some assistance on this task, I would be grateful.

Comment: You can't disable that (unless you want to try removing the JS listeners). Why do you need it disabled?

Comment: The current design uses rich:datatable, but we have a specific requirement to freeze the headers while scrolling down the table, thats why we changed the design to rich:extended-data-table. 

This change in design came with all other problems, one of them is this unwanted drag-n-drop column feature - which we don't need.

I have seen the text of the headers also are un-copiable now, users can't copy the text. But if I can remove the drag-n-drop feature for the table, it should be enough for now.

Thanks for your suggestion Mike

Comment: I don't understand the requirement, rearranging the columns is a client-side feature - it has no effect on the data or how other users see the table.