# Under a JSF Rich-Column, how can I suppress background color for an inserted table?

Tags: css, jsf-2, richfaces

I have posted another similar problem yesterday. Here's [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549922/in-richextendedtable-tag-how-can-i-set-the-drag-and-drop-property-for-the-colu).

Now I ran into a different problem. Under a rich-column of an extended data-table, I have added another 2 rich-datables. One table for the header, the other table for the table-data. All these were done to make sure our design doesn't get changed.

Now, coming to the problem, you can see the attached image down. [Intended Page Rendering][2]. This is what I need. But when the page loads, I generally get something like this [Actual Page rendering][3].

After looking through the generated HTML code, I can get the desired output by deselecting the background-color property of the `rf-dt` class. See the third image below.

[Generated HTML -code][4] - this shows by deselecting the background-color property of `rf-dt` class, I can achieve my purpose. But when I go to actual code and try to put the changes its not working... I tried to put this in the CSS class

```
.shipmentBrowseTable .rf-dt {
    background-color: none;
}
```

where `shipmentBrowseTable` is the styleclass for outer Extended-data-table - the same styleclass used for inner data-table too.

The above code is not giving me the intended result. If someone can help me with this, it would be great.

Comment: You've not linked the images properly. That said `.rf-dt` is a class for the entire table which means the background color is usually not visible because rows and headers have their own background colors.

Comment: I don't have enough points, to add more than 3 links, you need at least 10 points.

I'm trying for other work-around, possibly by taking off the alternate color from the entire table, so that it looks uniform.

If possible, put a reputation against my name.

Comment: Have you tried, I don't know, combining the images into one? You can also get rid of the link to your previous issue, it's not that relevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .shipmentBrowseTable .rf-dt {
background-color: none !important;
```

}

the `!important` tag should override most styles